# How to access full 128 bits in NEON instructions?

Tags: arm64, neon

I recently wrote a program that does some floating point calculations in Arm64 Assembly.
Since the numbers I'm dealing with can become really tiny, I now want to optimise the code so that it uses as much precision as possible.

I found out the NEON engine has 128-bit floating point registers instead of the 64 bits I'm currently working with, so I searched a way to use these for calculations. Every website I looked at tells me this should be possible, but when I try to do something like

`fmul v0, v1, v2`

I just get "error: invalid operand for instruction".

I'm using the M1 chip that should be capable of working with NEON instructions, and when I change it to

`fmul v0.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d`

there's no problem at all.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Or is it just impossible to use all the 128 bits of these registers at once?

Comment: The idea of the 128-bit `v` registers is to operate on two 64-bit double-precision values at once, which is what `fmul v0.2d, v1.2d, v2.2d` does.   Or four 32-bit values, etc.   That's SIMD: Single Instruction Multiple Data. It's the same floating point types and operations you had before, just more operations at a time.  Sure, you can load and store 128 bits at a time, but arithmetic is all on multiple elements of smaller size.  There's no 128-bit arithmetic.

Comment: For fractals as indicated by the comment in the answer and at least for Mandelbrot/Julia, the best bet is to use fixed point arithmetic that can hold 4.0 or where overflow from (x*x + y*y) >= 4.0 can be detected; remember to use Karatsuba multiplication both for the bignum multiplication AND for the complex multiplication (with 5 element wise additions and 3 element wise multiplications, instead of the standard 2+4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

True, the NEON registers are 128bit wide, but the maximum **data type** width is 64.

No consumer architecture known to me is capable of handling any 128bit data type.

PS : Is there a quad data type to begin with? I'm curious.

Comment: Thanks, though that's a bit frustrating. And `qn` registers (128-bit) seem to work for load/store instructions... but ok, I guess I'll have to find another way to solve that problem.

Comment: On AArch64 Linux, the `long double` data type is 128 bit, but code that uses it seems to just generate calls to helpers in libgcc.

Comment: Specifically, it's [IEEE quad precision, aka binary128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format).  But yes, it's a feature of the compiler rather than the hardware - all quad-precision arithmetic is done in software.  If OP needs extreme precision and can entirely sacrifice performance, that would be just the thing.

Comment: Since I'm trying to draw fractals, performance is really important - that's why I'm doing this in assembly. But maybe I'll try to build a more precise calculation system myself. Anyway, thanks for helping